# Raw ICMP WInsock, asynchronous I/O

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, select, winsock2

I'm doing a program that will permit me to ping a lot of different IPs simultaneously (around 50-70).

I also need to delay the sending of each packet by say 1 ms, for multiple reasons, notably not getting my packets dropped by some routers which drop ICMP packets when there's too much sent at once (which mine does, on the sending machine, not the receiving one).

So I did it in a separate thread a bit like that :

```
// Send thread
for (;;) {
   [...]
   for (int i = 0; i < ip_count; i++)
   {
      // Send() calls sendto()
      Send(m_socket, ip_array[i]);
      [...]
      Sleep(1); // Delay by 1 ms
   }
   [...]
   lock_until_new_send_operation();
}
```

And in another thread, thread I would like to receive the packets with select(), like that

```
// Receive thread
FD_ZERO(&m_fdset_read);
FD_SET(m_socket, &m_fdset_read);
int rds_count = select(0, &m_fdset_read, 0, 0, &tvtimeout);
if (rds_count > 0)
    ProcessReadySocket(); // Calls recv() and stuff
else {
    // Timed out
    m_bSendGrapeDone = true;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that since both calls to select() and sento() use the same non-blocking socket m_socket, calls to sendto() would later block because select() makes sendto() block when both are called simultaneously (for some strange reason... dont see such logic there, since socket is non blocking, but it still does, its ugly).

So I decided to use one socket exclusively for sending then and replaced the line

```
Send(m_socket, ip_array[i]);
```

with

```
Send(m_sendSock, ip_array[i]); // m_sendSock is dedicated to sending only
```

I read on MSDN that for raw sockets each socket receives all packets for the protocol the socket is set to (mine is IPPROTO_ICMP ofc). Here I quote :

> There are further limitations for applications that use a socket of
>   type SOCK_RAW. For example, all applications listening for a specific
>   protocol will receive all packets received for this protocol

SO I thought even though my packets are sent with m_sendSock, I could still receive them using select()/recv() on m_socket, turns out I can't, select() never returns the socket is readable. So I'm kind of stuck, I cannot use select() and send() at the same time. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

(by the way I want to use raw sockets, not builtin windows icmp functions)

TL;DR How can I send() and select() simultaneously? Because on the send thread, send() blocks as soon as select() gets called on the receive thread, even if I used FIONBIO on it (non blocking). If I use two different sockets, one for sending and one destined to receive, I receive nothing on the receiving socket...

Thanks!

Comment: `Sleep(1); // Delay by 1 ms` - this is not how [Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298.aspx) works. It is very likely, that the thread will be rescheduled **immediately**.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm not sure how it's revelant. Sleep is to delay sending between two packets, not to give away the time slice to another thread (but whether it does or not I don't really care).

Comment: It may not introduce a delay at all. Did you care to read the documentation at all?

Comment: I tested it multiple times and set the period accordingly. It does. That's the last of my priorities for now, I'd rather concentrate on making winsock related functions work. But by curiosity, what sentence are you referring to in the doc? I don't see anywhere they mention sleep would work so poorly?

Comment: *"If* dwMilliseconds *is less than the resolution of the system clock, the thread may sleep for less than the specified length of time."* The *Remarks* section is **not** optional reading. For your convenience: [Windows Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725496.aspx): *"[...] resolution of the system timer, which is approximately 10 milliseconds to 16 milliseconds."*

Comment: Oh I get you but as said I do a call to timeBeginPeriod() so that part was for me in some way irrevelant because already implied. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Try using overlapped I/O instead, i.e., WSASendTo, etc.

Comment: @Harry Johnston Indeed I thought about that, I wonder though (and it would answer my question fully), is that just not possible to do it the way I'm doing it at the moment? That's what I suspect but a confirmation from someone who had that knowledge would be nice (Im fairly beginner in sockets).

Comment: I don't know.  I would guess that the first problem is that you're using a synchronous socket from two threads simultaneously, I'm not certain but I suspect that's not permitted.  Instead, consider using a single thread; select() can tell you when the socket is ready for writing, and that *is* after all the way select() is meant to be used.  As for the second problem, my guess is that it's the firewall.  For testing purposes, turn the firewall off altogether; if that solves the problem, turn it back on and configure an exception.